# How to spy OKTA authStateService.authState$ in angular unit testing using karma jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, okta

I have the below authentication guard in my angular application which using OKTA to authenticate.

```js
    export class AuthenticationGuard implements canActivate {

    iaAuthenticated: boolean;
    userDetails: any = null;

    constructor(@Inject(OKTA_AUTH) private oktaAuth: OktaAuth, public authStateService:
        OktaAuthStateServuce) { }
    canActivate = async (next: aCtivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<any>
        => {
        try {
            this.authStateService.authState$.subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    this.isAuthenticated = response.isAuthenticated;
                }
            );
            if (this.isAuthenticated) {
                this.userDetails = this.oktaAuth.getUser();
            } else { return false; }
        } catch { return false; }
     }
    }
```

and this is the spec code for the same which I written

```js
    export class OktaAuthMock {
    isAuthenticated() {
        return true;
    }
    getUser() {
        return {
            email: ‘email@gmail.com’,
            name: ‘test’
        };
    }
    };

     authState$(){ 
       return {isAuthenticated: true}
     }

    fdescribe(‘test AuthenticationGuard’, () => {
    let service: AuthenticationGuard;
    beforeEach(() => {
        Testbed.configureTestingModule({
            Imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            Providers: [
                {
                    provide: OktaAuthStateService,
                    useClass: OktaAuthMock
                },
                {
                    Provide: OKTA_AUTH,
                    useValue: {}
                }
            ]
        )};
        service = Testbed.inject(AuthenticationGurad)
    });

    it(‘test canActivate method’, () => {
        const authService: OktaAuthStateService = Testbed.inject(OktaAuthStateService);
        spyOn<any>(authService. ‘authState$’).and.returnValue(of({ isAuthenticated: true }));
        service.canActivate(null, null);
        expect(service.canActivate).tobeTruthy();
    }); 
    )};
```

There is no error in the code but I tried to spyon the OktaAuthStateService like above and the lines of code in ts is not covered in unit test. Kindly help to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be a few items to address here.

1. Regarding your specific question about mocking Okta, you need to provide mocks for both `OKTA_AUTH` and `OktaStateService`. The mocks should match the calls being made. For example, you mocked a method `authState$()`, but in the `OktaStateService`, it's not a method, it's a property on the class.
2. You also haven't provided a mock for `OKTA_AUTH`. You'll want to do so, which will allow you to test this without importing the `HttpClientTestingModule`.
3. Your casing and spelling of the properties and definitions should be double-checked in both your guard as well as your test.
4. FWIW, if you are creating a guard, consider implementing from `CanActivate`. Or maybe this is a casing issue?

Here are some samples to reference as you work through this.

An example repo that shows how to implement a guard using Okta is [oktadev/okta-angular-material-login-example](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-angular-material-login-example). This is using an older version of the `okta-angular` SDK that doesn't use the `OKTA_AUTH` injection token, so you'll need to make appropriate adjustments. Of note look at

- [auth.guard.ts](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-angular-material-login-example/blob/main/src/app/auth.guard.ts)
- [auth.guard.spec.ts](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-angular-material-login-example/blob/main/src/app/auth.guard.spec.ts)

For examples of how to mock and spy on properties in Okta services, check out [oktadev/okta-angular-dynamic-components-example](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-angular-dynamic-components-example). Of note look at

- [profile.component.spec.ts](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-angular-dynamic-components-example/blob/main/src/app/profile/profile.component.spec.ts)

Comment: It would be helpful if there was an example that DOES use the OKTA_AUTH injection token.